# Why these tasks are starting delayed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am trying this code (just spawn some tasks and simulate work):

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(d => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Processing [{0}]", d);
    Task.Delay(20000).Wait(); // Simulate work. Here will be some web service calls taking 7/8+ seconds.
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Task Complete [{0}]", d);
    return (2 * d).ToString();
})).ToList();

var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
Console.Out.WriteLine("All processing were complete with results: {0}", string.Join("|", results));
```

I was expecting to see 10 `Processing ...` in the console at once; but when I run, initially I see this output

```
Processing [1]
Processing [2]
Processing [3]
Processing [4]
```

Then 1/2 seconds later `Processing [5]`, `Processing [6]` and others are shown slowly one after another.

Can you explain this? Does this mean tasks are being started as delayed? Why?

Comment: You're creating *long-running* tasks. You ought to be kind to the scheduler and find an appropriate overload so that you can *inform* the scheduler of this fact, via [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Wow! Just used that overload and, ta-da!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Can you post your comment as an answer (so that I can mark this as answered)?

Comment: The reason this happens is because by default tasks are scheduled using the threadpool, and threadpool thread creation is throttled when it exceeds the count given by `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads()`. Long running threads are not scheduled on the thread pool, so they don't get this behaviour.

Comment: Now another question, which `Task`s should I create with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option? >500 msec?

Comment: In practice? You shouldn't need this *at all*. If you have I/O work to do, use asynchronous I/O, no need to waste threads. If you have CPU work to do, adding more threads than you have CPU is at best limited by the amount of CPUs available and usually even worse. The thread-pool is configured based on how much concurrent CPU work you can do, because that's what those threads are for - blocking on some I/O operation is a waste all around :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you have 4 cpu cores.

Having two (cpu bond) threads fighting over a core leads to it taking longer to complete the work then have 1 thread doing the first task, then doing the second task run.

Until it know otherwise the task system assumes tasks are short running and CPU bound and that they will use “none blocking” IO.

Therefore I expect that the task systems defaults to the number of threads being close to the number of cores.

Using [TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> provides a hint to the TaskScheduler that oversubscription may be
>   warranted. Oversubscription lets you create more threads than the
>   available number of hardware threads.

**And lastly tasks are not threads, they are design to hide a lot of the details of threads from you, including controlling the number of threads that are in use.**   It is reasonable to create 100s of tasks, if you created 100s of threads all trying to run at the same time, the cpu cache etc will have a very hard time.

---

However lets get back to what you are trying to do.   Your example simulates CPU bound work. You say your tasks will be making calls to a web service - meaning they will be IO bound.

As such, they should be running asynchronously. However, `Task.Delay(20000).Wait();` waits synchronously, so it doesn't represent what will/should actually be going on.    See Gediminas Masaitis answer for a code sample using `await` to make the delay asynchronously.    However as soon as you use yet more asynchronously code, you need to think more about locking etc.

Asynchronously IO is clearly better if you have 100s of requests going on at the same time.    However if you just have a "hand full" and no other usage of `await` in your application then `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` may be good enough.

Comment: You don't need locking because of "more asynchronous code". You need it because of the concurrency (and even more precisely, sharing). `await` doesn't make this any more important than using synchronously blocking code on multiple threads. Synchronization is important even in single-threaded applications, if there's re-entrancy involved, for example.

Comment: @Luaan, Agree in the general case, but I have seen lots of application where calls to external servers (e.g. 3 membase lookups) can be done in parallel waiting for the result before continually without having to add any locking.   Adding “await” to a code base that does not already use it and is moistly single threaded increases how much each developer needs to understand.

Also often it is calls to SQL Server that can run on more then one connection,  asynchronously usage of SQL sever has never been nice...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer, using [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will solve your problem.

But this is not how you should approach your problem. Your example simulates *CPU bound* work. You say your tasks will be making calls to a web service - meaning they will be *IO bound*.

As such, they should be running *asynchronously*. However, `Task.Delay(20000).Wait();` waits *synchronously*, so it doesn't represent what will/should actually be going on.

Take this example instead:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(async d =>
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Processing [{0}]", d);
    await Task.Delay(5000); // Simulate IO work. Here will be some web service calls taking 7/8+ seconds.
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Task Complete [{0}]", d);
    return (2*d).ToString();
}).ToList();
var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
Console.Out.WriteLine("All processing were complete with results: {0}", string.Join("|", results));
```

All tasks start instantly as expected.